# Bounds for the number of self-conjugate partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

is there any upper bound for the number of self-conjugate partitions, or equivalently the number of partitions with distinct odd parts?

P.S.: I didn't get why my question has been moved to Math Stack Exchange and then closed. In fact I need a precise upper bound for the number of self-conjugate partitions and I haven't found anything in the literature. If it is obvious, could you please help me?

Comment: This is OEIS entry https://oeis.org/A000700. The references there surely include all information you'd want to know, including precise asymptotics.

Comment: The asymptotic behavior of your sequence (OEIS A000700) is stated on pg. 12 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08708. If you want something more precise, maybe specify in what way.

Comment: ok thank you, I have edited my question.